# Kendo UI + Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, kendo-ui

I'm trying to create some CRUD grids using Kendo UI + Codeigniter and i would like to ask if

anyone knows how to handle the Kendo scripts in the views. Is it better to use a common view

for all grids and pass each time the Kendo script as a paramater to the view or is it better

to use a separate view for each grid and hardcode the Kendo script in the view.

Or is there any better way?

Answer (score 2):

For a web application it would be better to keep its discreteness - so creating separate view for each grid and hardcoding kendo script in the views would be the best option.